# Yii2 Update Password

Tags: php, yii2

I'm building my password update function. But getting the error "hash invalid". Not 100% sure.

**User Controller**

```
$model = User::findOne(['id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
               $model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_PASSWORD;

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                // get values
                $post = Yii::$app->request->post('User'); 
                    // validate old password
                    if($model->validatePassword($post['password'])){
                        $model->password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($post['newPassword']);
                        // use new password
                        if($model->save()){
                            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Password Updated');
                            return $this->redirect(['user/profile']);
                        } else {
                            echo 'Couldn\'t save';
                        }
                    } else{
                        // incorrect password
                        $model->addError('newPassword', 'Incorrect Password');

                        return $this->render('jsUpdatePassword',[
                            'model' => $model,
                        ]); 
                    }
            }
```

My $post['password'] I expect to be the string of what I input which it is. I'm unsure why my hash would be invalid  though as it's calling `return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password);` in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting user `$model = User::findOne(['id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);` which is okey but after that you do `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`.
So now in Your model class `$this->password` is not from database but from post. Am I wrong? Please debug what You get in `$password, $this->password` variables when calling `validatePassword` method.

Comment: That makes sense, I have been getting the plain posted password as my $model password. So perhaps I need to not load() into $model, but another $var?

Comment: There can be many solutions for that. You can for exaple take a look how it is made in yii2 official basic template [link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic). Look at SiteController and LoginForm.